# Associated idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

Let $e$ and $f$ be elements of an associative algebra $A$. We say $e$ and $f$ are associated if there exist elements $x, y \in A$ such that: $$e = xy, f = yx.$$

My teacher said it is an easy exercise to show that the following is true: $$Ae \cong Af,$$ as left $A-$modules.

I have started by defining the map: $$ae \mapsto af.$$ The problem I have is showing that this map is injective as a module homomorphism, and in showing that the map is a surjective module homomorphism, I have not use the fact that the idempotents are associated, so I think that it is necessary here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, no, no. You only do that if you absolutely have to. The first thing you should try if you want to show that something is an isomorphism is to construct its inverse. When you can do that it's the most satisfying way, and often the easiest. (By the way, I debate the claim that your map is the obvious map. The problem is that it's not clear that it's well-defined.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok so I need to show that if $ae = a'e$ for $a,a' \in A$, then $af = a'f$. So if $ae = a'e$, then $axy = a'xy$ and therefore $(a-a')xy = 0$. Again I'm stuck at showing that $(a-a')yx = 0$ follows from the above.

Comment: Hmm. If we quotient $k\langle x,y,r\rangle$ by the two-sided ideal $(rx)$ to form $A$, then $rxy=0$ but I don't see why $ryx$ would have to be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remark: in general it is false that $Ae\simeq Af$ if $e=xy$ and $f=yx$. Take for example $A$ to be the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices, then
$$x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},y=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
This gives $e=xy=x\not=0$ and $f=yx=0$.

However, in your title you wrote "idempotents" so I presume that you wanted $e$ and $f$ to satisfy $e^2=e$, $f^2=f$.

Second remark: even in this case, the map that you defined is not necessarily well-defined. Take for example $A$ as before and
$$x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},y=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
This gives $e=xy=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $f=yx=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. And the two matrices do not have the same kernel.

Now, let us come to the proof of the fact hat $Ae\simeq Af$ if $e=xy$, $f=yx$, AND if $e^2=e$, $f^2=f$. Note that $e=xyxy=xfy$ and $f=yxyx=yex$. We define two maps

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
\psi \colon& Ae&\to& Af\\
&ae &\mapsto & axf
\end{array}$$ 
$$\begin{array}{rccc}
\phi \colon& Af&\to& Ae\\
&af &\mapsto & aye
\end{array}$$

If $a,a'\in A$ are such that $ae=a'e$, then $0=(a-a')e=(a-a')xy$, which implies that $0=(a-a')xyx=(a-a')xf$, so $axf=a'xf$. Hence, $\psi$ is well-defined. The same argument gives you that $\phi$ is well defined, and you can also compute that both maps are inverse from each other, and homomorphisms of $A$-modules.

For instance, $\phi(\psi(ae))=\phi(axf)=axye=ae^2=ae$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. :-)